# Leaflet - Add Features to a json Object and put the result on the map

Tags: javascript, json, csv, leaflet

I'm working on a Leaflet Map and i have a json object and I will want to add all the properties necessary and required by L.GeoJson of leaflets javascript.
So  i read the documentation and build a "FeatureCollection" with "Feature","Geometry" and "Properties", as described in the documentation at this [feature-objects](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects), so i create this piece of code in javascript:

```
 _addFeatureToJson: function(papaJson){
    papaJson["type"]="FeatureCollection";
    papaJson["features"]=[];
    var title = papaJson.meta.fields;
    for (var num_linea = 0; num_linea < papaJson.data.length - 1; num_linea++) { //  var depth = papaJson.data.length - 1;
        var obj = papaJson.data[num_linea]; //single element of papa parse json object
        var fields = title.toString().trim().split(",");
        var lng = parseFloat(obj[this.options.longitudeTitle]);
        var lat = parseFloat(obj[this.options.latitudeTitle]);
        if (fields.length+"=="+title.length && lng<180 && lng>-180 && lat<90 && lat>-90) {
            var feature = {};
            feature["type"]="Feature";
            feature["geometry"]={};
            feature["properties"]={};
            feature["geometry"]["type"]="Point";
            feature["geometry"]["coordinates"]=[lng,lat];
            var content ='<div class="popup-content"><table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">';
            for (var i=0; i< title.length; i++) {
                if (title[i] != this.options.latitudeTitle && title[i] != this.options.longitudeTitle) {
                    if(title[i]==this.options.titleForSearch){
                        feature["properties"]["search"]=obj[title[i]];
                        feature["properties"]["title"]=obj[title[i]];
                    }else{
                        feature["properties"][title[i]] = this._deleteDoubleQuotes(obj[title[i]]);
                        var href='';
                        if (obj[title[i]].indexOf('http') === 0) {
                            href = '<a target="_blank" href="' + obj[title[i]] + '">'+ obj[title[i]] + '</a>';
                        }
                        if(href.length > 0)content += '<tr><th>'+title[i]+'</th><td>'+ href +'</td></tr>';
                        else content += '<tr><th>'+title[i]+'</th><td>'+ obj[title[i]] +'</td></tr>';
                    }
                }//end of if
            }//end of for
            content += "</table></div>";
            feature["properties"]["popupContent"]=content;
            papaJson["features"].push(feature);           
        }
    }

    return papaJson;
}
```

After add the feature with the "popupContent" field, when i load the Json on LeafletMap all marker are corrected create, but when i click on them the popup is just inexistent, here the piece of code for load the Json object.

```
 _loadGeoJSON: function (content) {
    if (typeof content == 'string') {
        content = JSON.parse(content);
    }
    var layer = L.geoJson(content, this.options.layerOptions);

    if (layer.getLayers().length === 0) {
        throw new Error('GeoJSON has no valid layers.');
    }

    if (this.options.addToMap) {
        layer.addTo(this._map);
    }
    return layer;
},
```

Here i have a JSFiddle snippet [test with jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4535992/gynog5nx/), here the file csv for the test [file csv for test](https://github.com/p4535992/repositoryForTest/blob/master/testWitSources/fileForTest/data.csv), ty in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you copied Leaflet GeoJSON tutorial by writing the html content that you want to be in popups in a `popupContent` field / property of your GeoJSON objects. Indeed, it is a good place to store that content.

However, it is not automatically transformed into an actual popup bound to your markers.

Please inspect the source code of [Leaflet tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) in details and you will see that they use a function `onEachFeature` to read that content and transform it into a popup.

```js
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    var popupContent = "<p>I started out as a GeoJSON "
        + feature.geometry.type + ", but now I'm a Leaflet vector!</p>";

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // popupContent property to actual popup
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
        popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
    }

    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gynog5nx/1/

Comment: yes, you're right, I do not know why I had put in my head that would create Leaflet automatically popup on the marker, if I created the property "popupContent".